# moment JS returns wrong date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm passing UTC timestamp to moment js and timezone in order to get back the real date.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
formatDate: function(dateTime, timezone) {
    var format = 'D-MMM-YYYY';
    return moment.utc(dateTime, format).tz(timezone).format(format);
}
```

So I would pass on something like `formatDate(1399922165, 'America/Los_Angeles');` and it returns 12-Jan-9992 instead of 12-May-2014.

If instead I do it like this:

```
moment(dateTime).tz(timezone).format(format);
```

Then it returns 16-Jan-1970.

Thanks to Ian, this ended up being the solution.

```
moment.unix(dateTime).tz(timezone).format(format);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `1399922165` does not match the format `'D-MMM-YYYY'`...

Comment: Maybe you meant to use: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/ ?

Comment: Ahh Ian, you are right.  I was looking at utc but that didn't work.  unix does.

Comment: Please move your edit to an answer (you *can* answer your own question).  Thanks.

Comment: I did not do `moment.utc(datetime,format)`, I was using the `.format()` method which is the output format, not input format.

Comment: Yes you originally did. It's right there in your code. Even if you answer your own question, the answer is not for yourself: it's for future readers. They will see the question, they will read your code, and they will and wonder.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I see it now. Format was used twice, should have only been in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ian, this ended up being the solution.

```
moment.unix(dateTime).tz(timezone).format(format);
```

I was trying `moment.utc()` instead of `moment.unix()`.

The strange results came from `moment.utc(datetime, format)` expecting `datetime` to match `format`. However, it's important to note that `moment.utc(datetime)` still returns 1970 year result so it still wouldn't have returned the desired result even without the format.